# Event keys and click

Tags: c#, .net

after many searches on the internet, I can’t find an optimized solution. Indeed, I would just like to block keys and mouse click at some point, however I would like to avoid putting all the keys and clicking in my condition. Is this possible?

There is the code :

```
private void cmdVision_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        pnlNote.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void cmdVision_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        pnlNote.Enabled = false;
    }
    //MAJ4
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right || e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
    {
        pnlNote.Enabled = false;
    }
    //MAJ4
}
```

As you can see my condition consists of e.Button == MouseButtons.Right || e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle.
So I would like to avoid having to do that for every key on the keyboard.

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: You should set a condition variable for the case when you need the block an evaluate it in the event. If the condition is true you can return from the event handler without ever having to check the keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [`PreviewKeyDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.8) event and its [`PreviewKeyDownEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.previewkeydowneventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2). There are a set of helpful properties, like `IsInputKey` and `KeyCode` (you can compare pressed key with the range of key codes).